# UK Tier 4 visa question regarding countries I have visited

Tags: visas, uk, study, applications

It asks for the countries I have been in the last 10 years, including the date of travel and the reason why I went there. The problem is that although I DO remember where I went and why, I do not remember at all when I went there. Does someone know what to do in such a case?

Comment: Look at your travel history in your passport, and in your airline website?

Comment: Problem is that I cannot find my previous passports. I changed it to a new one last year, and all my travels are recorded in the previous one. Also, I don't really remember which Airlines I used and I don't think I have the e-mails from them anymore as I probably have deleted them.

Comment: Do as best as you can do it. Just do not lie (so put a "approximate"). Approximate date and length is the most important thing.  Note: if you have Android (and you connected to WiFi), probably google known where you were (check your travel history/timeline)

Answer (score 2):

I did a search for some help and noticed that many UK universities have a student welfare department that offers some help with Tier 4 applications (https://www.google.com/search?q=uk+visa+tier+4+travel+history&oq=uk+visa+tier+4+travel+history&ie=UTF-8).  Of those that I cared to look at, the most helpful seemed to be this from the University of Oxford's "Guide to completing Tier 4 (General) Student Online Application" (last updated 1 Mar 2018):

> **International Travel History**
>
> You are asked to record visits to a list
>   of five countries plus the Schengen area in the past 10 years.
>   Follow the instructions and if you cannot remember all of them,
>   include this information in the ‘additional information’ section at
>   the end of the form
>
> The form continues to ask about travel to all other counties.  Again
>   answer this to the best of your ability and if you are a frequent
>   traveller include this in the ‘additional information’ section at the
>   end

Maybe your university offers some specific advice and be aware that advice might change at any time.

Comment: I have checked a lot of guides from different universities, but they just state to put in the exact date I went there, which is also the reason for my problem as I really do not remember, and the most I can remember is the year that I went, but it is not useful as it also requires a month and a date. I would send an e-mail to the VISA, but they still have not answered a e-mail I sent 2 months ago regarding a question, so I better ask somewhere else since I need it  for next month...